# Can't disk partition with GParted

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, gparted

I have both Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS and Windows 10. I need some space for Ubuntu, so I wanted to transfer some disk space from Windows to Ubuntu. When I tried that, I have got a problem.

For convenience, I added a picture. As seen in pic, I have got two parts:

- the `/` mount point
- the `/home` directory

When I try to move my unallocated part, the "/" directory doesn't allow me. In a nutshell, how can I transfer my 35 GBs of space to Ubuntu?

[image: Partition View in GParted]

Thanks for all your bits of help.

Comment: When I tried to manipulate Windows partitions with gparted, it wrecked my Windows install.  Based on my experience, I would only manipulate Windows partitions with Windows tools.  As far as your actual question, you cannot move partitions that are in use (I assume that is what the black bar icon means - on my systems it is a padlock icon). You must boot from a live usb or cd to work with these partitions.

Comment: Got it, thanks. I opened the free space in Windows. Is there a tool in Windows to move free space to Ubuntu?
Is there a topic you can suggest for me to use as a guide?

Comment: It's been a long time, but there is a tool in Windows that lets you shrink the Windows partition. Then you go to the live USB and grow the Ubuntu partition.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions). You seem to be describing a classic duplicate of that question. Read all the dual-boot answers, not just the top couple.

Comment: Thanks, I hope so. I will try it.

Comment: Seeing that all your main partitions are filling up, I would think about getting an external drive and putting Ubuntu on it.  Moving/working on partitions can cause loss of data, so backup is strongly recommended.